# iOS App Hangs on Launch Screen in Debug

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I've been working a project for several years and Xcode has occasionally given me trouble, but this one has me stumped.

The app was running as I expected while I was debugging Store Kit and downloading issues. I added a required delegate method for NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate and attempted to run the app to see how the change worked. The app hung on the launch screen and continues to do so.

So far, I've tried:
Allowing the launch screen to show for 5 min (waiting),
deleting the app from the device,
cleaning the project,
cleaning the build folder,
restarting the device,
restarting my Mac,
regenerating my developer cert and provisioning profile, as well as a few other suggestions I've seen in somewhat related Stackoverflow questions. (Most of the issues with hanging on the launch screen seem to be related to the simulator.)

I've put a breakpoint on the first line of the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in the app delegate, and the breakpoint is never reached.

Another project runs fine from Xcode on the same device. The problematic project hangs on another device and in the simulator. I'm running Xcode 5.1.1.

---

I'm adding this comment to document how this was resolved.

After many days of troubleshooting, I determined that the main run loop was never being started by UIApplicationMain(). So, I opened a ticket with Apple.

Apple determined that the issue was in reading from plist in a dispatch_once() queue in an initialize method in one of my classes. It seems that a dispatch_once() can be executed before the app bundle exists. So, reading the plist from the bundle is not possible and results in a hang.

Comment: If you revert the changes you made, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does! Good thought. I think the problem is related to some exploring I was doing -- I started to convert the app from xibs to a storyboard, but decided it would be too much work for no user benefit and discarded the changes. Something that was changed did not revert. I'm still investigating.